# How to convert postgres sql to mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have the query in postgres sql like below:

```
-- Table: album
   CREATE TABLE album
   (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    artist character varying(255),
    title character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_album PRIMARY KEY (id )
   )
   WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
   );
   ALTER TABLE album
   OWNER TO developer;

  -- Table: track
     CREATE TABLE track
     (
     track_id bigserial NOT NULL,
     track_title character varying(255),
     album_id bigint,
     CONSTRAINT track_pkey PRIMARY KEY (track_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_track_album FOREIGN KEY (album_id)
     REFERENCES album (id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
  WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
   );
     ALTER TABLE track
    OWNER TO developer;
```

And now I need to convert it to mysql query. But I am confused. How can I do that tutorials? Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "MySQL" and not "SQL Server" by "mysql server".  I've modified the question and title to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you want to handle the ownership constructs in MySQL, but the table definitions can be readily converted:

```
CREATE TABLE album (
    id bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,
    artist varchar(255),
    title varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_album PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE track (
    track_id bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,
    track_title varchar(255),
    album_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT track_pkey PRIMARY KEY (track_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_track_album FOREIGN KEY (album_id)
    REFERENCES album (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f65fc) is the SQL Fiddle.

The [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ec62) version isn't much different:

```
CREATE TABLE album (
    id bigint NOT NULL identity,
    artist varchar(255),
    title varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_album PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE track (
    track_id bigint NOT NULL identity,
    track_title varchar(255),
    album_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT track_pkey PRIMARY KEY (track_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_track_album FOREIGN KEY (album_id)
    REFERENCES album (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Thank u very much Mr. Gordon. That is what I looking for. :-D